# How to evaluate variable names inside a text expression in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter package eval_ex to evaluate math expression.

For example, my math expression: `21+5*(e^(-1))+log(8)-9-(2^3)/6`

```
exp = Expression("21+5*(e^(-1))+log(8)-9-(2^3)/6").eval().toString();
```

I know the following:

```
a = 21
b = 5*(e^(-1))
c = log(8)-9
d = (2^3)/6
```

My goal is evaluate the expression using variable names: `a+b+c-d`

```
exp = Expression(a+b+c-d).eval().toString();
```

Could you please provide any suggestions.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://pub.dev/packages/expressions, which seems to be a parser/evaluator for your complex expressions?  If not enough, I'd look at its source code, as it is based on PetitParser, which is a fairly general-purpose lexer/parser that can do pretty much anything you might want.